# the token gave me nothing and i chek my code Many times

Tags: javascript, flutter, api, dart, dio

**the token get null**
the function dio **

```
 static Future<Response> getData(
      {@required String url, String token, lang = 'ar'}) async {
    dio.options.headers = {
      'lang': lang,
         'Authorization': '$token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };



return await dio.get(url);
```

}
*pass values*

```
  void GetData()async {
    emit(Loading_Data());
   await DioHelper.getData(url: Home_, token: token,).then((value) {
      homedata = Home.fromjson(value.data);
     

  emit(Success_Data());
}).catchError((onError){print(onError.toString());
emit(EROOR_Data());

    });
  }
```

*function call in main*
*i use bloc*

```
 providers: [
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => ShopingCupit()..GetData(),
      ),
```

*why the token get null*
**thanks**

Comment: You are not calling `getData`. If you are calling it, include that code.

Comment: i calling and everything work but the token  gave me null

Comment: Include how you call the function in the question

Comment: BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => ShopingCupit()..GetData(),
          ),

Comment: void GetData() {
    emit(Loading_Data());
    DioHelper.getData(url: Home_, token: token).then((value) {
      homedata = Home.fromjson(value.data);
     
    
      emit(Success_Data());
    }).catchError((onError){print(onError.toString());
    emit(EROOR_Data());

    });
  }

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please update your question with the usage code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because u didn't pass the token here return await dio.get(url);

try return await dio.get(url, token);

Comment: i did but  get null